# Assuming $f(x)$ is a continuous function of $x$ and finding $F'(x)$

Tags: calculus

> Find $F'(x)$ for
>   $$F(x)=\int_0^x[x^2+f(t)]\,\mathrm dt.$$

The question mentions that the answer is **not** $F'(x) = x^2 + f(x)$.

By using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus,
$$F'(x)=\frac{\mathrm dF(x)}{\mathrm dt}-\frac{\mathrm dF(0)}{\mathrm dt}= x^2+f(x).$$
What did I do wrong?

Comment: Note that $x^2$ term is constant in the integral because it is done with respect to $t$, i.e d$t$

Comment: So since x is a constant then $x^2$ is a constant and so is $f(x)$. Therefore $F'(x) = 0$ ?

Comment: Try computing $\int_0^x x^2 \mathrm{d}t$. What do you get?

Comment: $x^2t$ from 0 to x, so $x^3$

Comment: correct, so the the new thing you differentiate with respect to $x$ is $x^3 + \int_0^x f(t) \mathrm{d}t$

Comment: Thank you! @rubikscube09 You should put it as an answer to get points

Comment: Someone's already done it for me. No worries

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rewrite as 
$$
F(x)=\int_0^x x^2\, dt+\int_{0}^x f(t)\, dt=x^2\int_0^x\,dt+\int_0^xf(t)\, dt=x^3+\int_0^x f(t)\,dt
$$
which is a more amenable form to differentiate and apply FTC.